# How to validate the length of Variable Arguments (Varargs) at compile time?

Tags: java, validation, compilation, variadic-functions

I want to write a function to do replacing in string template with varargs, for example:

```java
public static String replace (String original, String... replacements) {
    for (int i = 0; i < replacements.length; i += 2) {
        original = original.replace(replacements[i], replacements[i + 1];
    }
}
```

so I can call this function like:

```java
String replaces = replace("NAME TIME", "NAME", "Abc", "TIME", "20:12");
```

Apparently, `replacements.length` should be a multiple of `2` and I want to validate this at compile time, I want to achieve something like:

```java
@ValidateVarargs("length % 2 == 0", "replacements.length must be a multiple of 2")
public static String replace (String original, String... replacements) {
    for (int i = 0; i < replacements.length; i += 2) {
        original = original.replace(replacements[i], replacements[i + 1];
    }
}
```

And when I call this function with odd number of replacement strings, It will give me some compilation errors like:

```
Compilation error: replacements.length must be a multiple of 2
At path/to/Xxx.java line yyy (where this function was called)
```

Is it possible? If possible, how to do it?

Or, if this can not be achieved by using Annotations, is there any IDE or IDE plugin or some other thing can do this validation before or during compiling?

Thanks.

Comment: How would you expect it to be validated if I pass in a random `String[]`?

Comment: @Sweeper Oh, I missed this, well then I think it might be pretty difficult or impossible to achieve this only by language or compiler itself. Maybe I need something like a code analyzer plugin

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to redesign your api. Having method invocations with multiple string arguments in a row makes it difficult to tell which is the string being replaced and the replacement.

I would think of something like that:

```
StringReplacement.builder()
    .replace("being replaced", "replacement")
    .replace("yet another", "replacement")
    .build()
    .replace(stringToRunReplacementsOn);
```

Comment: Thank you for your replying! and yes, for the specific situation in this question, your answer is a better approach, but I still want to know the answer to the question itself, that is, how to validate varargs at compile time. ;-) sorry I want to vote you up but my reputation is too low